# asp:RadioButtonList add RadioButton to new line

Tags: c#, asp.net

The problem is as:
I have horizontal asp:RadioButtonList, with 3 buttons witch i add programaticly  C# code
The thing is that the third button must be on second line. How can i do it besides creating  a new asp:RadioButtonList?
I have tried adding br and \r\n to caption but that dose not help me.

```
ListItem _item1 = new ListItem("1", "1");
ListItem _item2 = new ListItem("2", "2");
ListItem _item3 = new ListItem("3", "3");
rbl.Items.Add(_item1);
rbl.Items.Add(_item2);
rbl.Items.Add(_item3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the RepeatColumns property ? Set it to 2 and the third one should bump down a line. This creates a column approach. Only downside to it if the labels are long it might not look right.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.repeatcolumns.aspx

If the labels are really long, then I would suggest moving to a repeater or listview and roll your own. You could use a placeholder control in the item template and in the itemdatabound event add the radio buttons based the count or index and use a mod to decide when to place a break element. Definitely a hack though.

Comment: but is it possible to add colspan to td?

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using [CssAdapters](http://www.asp.net/CssAdapters/) they offer a lot of flexibility for tweaking control layouts.